# Does ClickHouse support Encryption at rest?

Tags: clickhouse

Title says it all - is there any support for data encryption at rest in Clickhouse? I'm not interested in encrypted communication/replication, what I care about is data encryption at rest.

Kind regards
Tomasz

Comment: Clickhouse has released the encryption feature. Please check the official document: https://clickhouse.com/docs/en/sql-reference/functions/encryption-functions/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not yet. It's in the roadmap. And under development https://github.com/ClickHouse/ClickHouse/pull/11844

Comment: Denny, this feature has been released by Clickhouse. The pull request you mentioned was merged and here is the official document: https://clickhouse.com/docs/en/sql-reference/functions/encryption-functions/